# Google Dataproc writing from a client app uses cluster's internal IP for Datanodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, google-cloud-dataproc, pentaho-data-integration, datanode

I have setup a Dataproc cluster on Google Cloud.
It is sup and running and I can access HDFS and copy files from the SSH 'in browser" console. So the problem is not on the Dataproc side.

I am now using Pentaho (ELT software) to copy files.
Pentaho needs to access the Master and the Data Nodes.

I have the following error message :

```
456829 [Thread-143] WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer - Abandoning BP-1097611520-10.132.0.7-    1611589405814:blk_1073741911_1087
456857 [Thread-143] WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer - Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.132.0.9:9866,DS-6586e84b-cdfd-4afb-836a-25348a5080cb,DISK]
456870 [Thread-143] WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer - DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/jmonteilx/pentaho-shim-test-file.test could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and 2 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)
```

The IP address used in the log is the internal IP of my firs datanode in Dataproc.
I need to use the External IP.

My question is the following,

Anything to change in the config files in the client file to do so ?

I have tried :

```
<property>    
        <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>    
        <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Without success,
Many thanks,

Comment: Where are you running Pentaho ETL tool? On GCE VMs, on your local machine, on-prem data center or some other cloud?

Comment: I am using Pentaho on premise

Comment: Let me add that I have created the user using pentaho in the Linux master node VM as well as in HDFS

Answer (score 2):

ETL tool can not access DataNodes via external IPs from the on premise data center because probably your firewall rules block access from internet or you created [Dataproc cluster with internal IPs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network#create_a_cloud_dataproc_cluster_with_internal_ip_address_only).

That said, allowing access to HDFS from internet is a **security risk**. By default Dataproc cluster do not configure secure authentication w/ Kerberos, so if you decide to open up cluster to internet you at very least should [configure secure access](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/security) to it.

Preferred solution is to establish secure network connection between on premise and GCP clusters and access HDFS via it. You can read more about options for this in [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs).